# Keycloak: how do you disable TOTP from the admin REST API?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

The `UserRepresentation` contains a `totp` member. The [23.0.0 docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/23.0.0/rest-api/index.html) show this as an optional boolean, but it's otherwise undocumented. After some experimenting, I think that:

1. This field isn't writeable
2. If you read it, it returns true if TOTP is enabled for that user, *and* has been set up

The other alternative is `requiredActions`. If you add `CONFIGURE_TOTP` to the array you can enable TOTP, but if you remove CONFIGURE_TOTP from the array TOTP remains enabled.

So what have I missed? How do I turn off TOTP? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. In 23.0.1 you can disable OTP manually from the UI by going to users > credentials, and deleting the OTP credential. If you get a debug window in the browser and check the network activity this turns into a `DELETE /admin/realms/{realm}/users/{id}/credentials/{credentialId}`.

The only difficult bit is getting the `credentialId`. To do this, `GET /admin/realms/{realm}/users/{id}/credentials`, which returns an array of `CredentialRepresentation`. If you have an object with a type of `otp` then that's your OTP credential, and the associated `id` is the required `credentialId`.

The only other confusing part is that `totp` in the user's `UserRepresentation` is actually read-only. It sets itself true when the user has completed OTP setup. The UI behaves in exactly the same way: if you select your user, and look at the credentials tab, the OTP credential doesn't appear till the user has completed setup and logged in with a TOTP.